# Python: Not able to resolve global variable error

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Even after i declare the variables as global I get this error as global name not defined. I am not sure sure if I have declared the variable as global in the right place.

What I am trying to do in this program is from the function lux() I read the raw data from a sensor into var. The sensor raw data has two values, luminosity and IR. I am assigning them to channel0 and channel1 respectively. 
In the function getLux() I  am using channel0 and channel1 to calculate gain values.

Please help me resolve this error

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import smbus

from smbus import SMBus

address = 0x39
control = 0x03
tsl = SMBus(1)
pause = 0.08

def lux():
    #global channel0
    #global channel1
    print "Workking"
    tsl.write_byte(address, 0x80)
    tsl.write_byte(address, control)

    var = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    var = tsl.read_i2c_block_data(0x39, 0x8d)
    channel0 = ((var[1]<<8) + var[0])
    channel1 = ((var[3]<<8) + var[2])

    print "total light %5d     IR light %5d" % (channel0, channel1)
    time.sleep(2)
    return (channel0, channel1)

def setGain(gain):
    if (gain == 1):
            tsl.write_byte_data(address, 0x81, 0x01)
    elif (gain == 16):
            tsl.write_byte_data(address, 0x81, 0x11)
    time.sleep(pause)

def getLux(gain):
    global channel0
    global channel1

    if (gain == 1 or gain == 16):
            setGain(gain)
            ambient = lux(channel0)
            IR = lux(channel1)

    elif (gain == 0):
            setGain(16) #first try high gain
            ambient = channel0
            if (ambient < 65535):
                    IR = channel1
            if (ambient >= 65535):
                    setGain(1) #set low gain
                    ambient = channel0
                    IR = channel1

    if (gain == 1):
            ambient *= 16 #scale 1x to 16x
            IR *= 16

   if (float(ambient == 0)):
            ratio = 9999

    else:
            ratio = (IR / float(ambient))

    if (ratio >= 0) & (ratio <= 0.52):
            tlux = (0.0315 * ambient) - (0.0593 * ambient * (ratio**1.4))
    elif (ratio <= 0.65):
            tlux = (0.299 * ambient) - (0.0291 * IR)
    elif (ratio <= 0.80):
            tlux = (0.0157 * ambient) - (0.018 * IR)
    elif (ratio <= 1.3):
            tlux = (0.00338 * ambient) - (0.0026 * IR)
    elif (ratio > 1.3):
            tlux = 0

    return tlux



while True:

    print "LUX High Gain ", getLux(16)
    print "LUX Low Gain ", getLux(1)
    print "LUX AUTO Gain ", getLux()
```

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lux2.py", line 85, in <module>
    print "LUX High Gain ", getLux(16)
  File "lux2.py", line 45, in getLux
    ambient = lux(channel0)
NameError: global name 'channel0' is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign channel0 and channel1 as attributes to the getLux function:

```
getLux(gain, channel0, channel1)
```

Then the execution code could look like this:

```
while True:
    channels = lux() # This creates a tuple with channel variables
    print "LUX High Gain ", getLux(16, channels[0], channels[1])
    print "LUX Low Gain ", getLux(1, channels[0], channels[1])
    print "LUX AUTO Gain ", getLux(0, channels[0], channels[1])
```

This way you won't need to declare them as global which is usually considered as an unsafe practice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, I am seeing is that you haven't initialize the global variable. you need to Initialize the global variable inside the getLux function like.

```
global channel0
global channel1

channel0 = 0
channel1 = 0
```

this will solve the problem.

Instead of using the **global** keyword. you could declare the channel0, channel1 globally to access, assign & reassign in any function.